# Can I add my own adverts in my own Android application? Isn't that against the terms of use?

Tags: android, google-play, ads

I'm developing an Android app for a very specific region, so I would like to sell banners for myself and show them in my app. I'm not interested in Admob. I know how to do that but I was wondering if that goes against terms of use or something, or maybe my application could be deleted from Google Play.

Thank you!
(Sorry for my English!)

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that is not against the Terms of Service.

You can use Admob, Mobfox, Airplay... etc. As three examples of Android Ad providers.

You may need to be careful about the content of the Ads, as that would be problematic if you have adult ads on a "For all ages" App.